# Is the Jordan content a pre-measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently dealing with the theory of the Jordan content $\iota: \mathcal{J}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ where $\mathcal{J}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the ring of Jordan-measurable sets. I asked myself the question, whether it is a pre-measure. Let $(A_k) \in \mathcal{J}(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a disjoint set-sequence such that $\biguplus_{k=1}^\infty A_k \in \mathcal{J}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

From finite additivity and monotonicity of the Jordan content, we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \iota(A_k)=\iota \left( \biguplus_{k=1}^n A_k \right) \leq \iota \left( \biguplus_{k=1}^\infty A_k \right)$$

and thus $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \iota(A_k) \leq \iota( \biguplus_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to prove the other ineqality (or provide a counterexample) and would appreciate any hint you could give me.

Comment: The notion of $\sigma$-additivty is only defined for functions whose domain is a $\sigma$-algebra. Being a pre-measure and being $\sigma$-additive are related, but distinct concepts. Just scratch the $\sigma$-additivity part from the question altogether. To answer the question: yes, it is. The Jordan content is the restriction of the Lebesgue measure (a bona fide measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra) to the Jordan-measurable sets. I can't think about a "direct" argument at the moment, though.

Comment: @Thorgott: that is false. It also works in Rings and Semi-rings. A set function $\mu$ on a ring or semi-ring  $\mathcal{R}$ is $\sigma$-additive if whenever $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathcal{R}$ is a pairwise disjoint sequence such that $\bigcup_nA_n\in \mathcal{R}$, $\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)=\sum_n\mu(A_n)$.

Comment: @MateuszMajchrzak: Considering the semi-ring generated by the bounded intervals $(a,b]$, the Jordan "content" is  monotone, finitely additive and countably sub additive. The procedures of Lebesgue-Carathepdory used this facts to construct an extension to a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the Borel sets which is the so called Lebesgue measure on the real line. See Kallenberg, Foundations of Probability.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that to have a pre-measure, you must have two structures: a Boolean algebra (which is like $\sigma$-algebra, but only with closedness under finite unions) and a pre-measure itself.

*Definition (Pre measure) Let $\mathcal{B}_0$ be a Boolean algebra. A pre-measure $\mu_0$ on $\mathcal{B}_0$ is a finitely additive measure
$$\mu_0: \mathcal{B}_0 \to [0,+\infty]$$
with the property that*

4. $\mu_0 \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_0(E_n)$ whenever $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are disjoint sets in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ is in $\mathcal{B}_0$.

Now for Jordan content we have a Jordan algebra, i.e., the set of all Jordan measurable sets $\mathcal{J}$ satisfies our Boolean algebra axioms. But is Jordan content $\sigma$-additive, if the Boolean algebra allows for it?

Consider the set of rational numbers $q \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. Then each $q$ is Jordan measurable, yet the whole set is too entangled with $[0,1]$ so that the Jordan measure digresses to 1 instead of 0 thus damaging the $\sigma$-additivity (see [this answer](https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory/exercise_1-1-18?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link) for a more rigorous treatment).

Thus, although Jordan measurable sets define a Boolean algebra, the Jordan measure itself fails to be $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Please make your affiliation explicit, as per the comment above. Regards,